# Getting a lot of "undefined reference to" errors at linking stage from library that is not even used in the project

Tags: c++, qt, linker, vtk, point-cloud-library

I am getting a lot of undefined reference to errors at linking stage, looking similar to this:

```
libQt5Sql.so.5: undefined reference to `QAbstractTableModel::~QAbstractTableModel()@Qt_5'
```

The problem is that I am not even using Qt in my project. The only possible connection to Qt is that I am using Vtk and PCL, which were linked to Qt during their compilation. And adding paths to libQt5Sql, libQt5Core etc doesn't help, more and new undefined reference to errors appear. The same code with the same settings works on another PC. What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've spent 2 days trying to solve this, and found the solution right after posted the question here. The thing I needed to do is to add the path to Qt libs:

```
export  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/vaheta/Qt5.6.3/5.6.3/gcc_64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```